# Clear browser cache on React Vite build bundle

Tags: reactjs, vite, browser-cache, dev-to-production

For a new production build on a React/Vite app, I'd need to clear a browser cache, otherwise there is an error:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

The browser specifically would be looking for `index.6b47bc15.js` resulted from a previous build, while `index.ddb760e3.js` would be the current build.

I have inserted this into the html header but it did not help:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
```

Is there a way to clear the cache so the browser does not look for the previous build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

`content="public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0"`

The answer might actually however be to do with what is serving your webapp. For example with AWS s3/cloudfront you can set cache control as follows:

https://how.wtf/set-cache-control-on-s3-objects-using-the-aws-cli.html